# How to implement Docusign in Partner Community

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I tried to implement Docusign for Salesforce Partner Community.

I can give partner community user accès to Docusign, when I clicked on the button Send with Docusign, I have the Docusign Page and can select a template.

Then when I clicked on "Next" or "Send Now " button I have an error.

"The partner community is down for maintenance
Sorry for the inconvenience. We'll be back shortly."

Did anyone knows why I have this message ? Did you already implement Docusign in a Partner community ?

Comment: it does not look like DocuSign is available for community users out-of-the-box, but please check https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W00006I1escSAB/can-docusign-for-salesforce-used-for-community-users and https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W00006I1fGxSAJ/will-docusign-support-for-salesforce-community-users

Answer (score 0):

The managed package from the AppExchange does not apply to Community pages. Community Users are not members of your DocuSign account and cannot leverage DocuSign from within Salesforce.

There are however some recipes so that you can build out this type of desired functionality within your SFDC Community pages/portal: https://www.docusign.com/blog/extending-docusign-salesforce-recipes-success/